# Maximum Profit of stock selling such that there is atmost "L" days difference between buying and selling

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to solve Stock Selling problem by using Max Difference algorithm, but I'm not able to solve for the condition `i<j<=i+l`, where `i` is the index of day of buying and `j` is index of selling , `l` is the maximum days stock must be sold. I need O(n) algorithm.

```
/* 
Maximum absolute difference with i<j<=i+l   --> 
Keeping track of two elements --> 
Max difference and minimum element found so far --> O(n) 
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int maxDifference(int arr[] , int size , int l){
    int max = abs(arr[1] - arr[0]) ;
    int min = arr[0] ;
    int minIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = 1;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < size ; i++){

        if(abs(arr[i] - min) > max){
            maxIndex = i;
            printf("%d maxOuter\n",i);
            if((maxIndex - minIndex) <= l && minIndex < maxIndex){
                printf("%d max\n",i);
                max = arr[i] - min ;
            }
        }

        if(arr[i] <= min){
            printf("%d min\n",i);
            min = arr[i] ;
            minIndex = i ;
        }

    }
    return max;
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = { 
        2, 3, 1, 15, 4, 8, 15, 35, 1, 55, 203, 3, 450, 550, 100, 600}; //3 and 600
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int l = 5;
    printf("%d" , maxDifference(arr , size , l)) ;
}
```

Comment: Does `max` need to change if `min` changes?

Comment: No need of changing max if min changes. Only problem is the window of L days. In the array given as input answer should be 597 (from 3 and 600) but since 1 is minimum my algorithm ignores this part and scans only till next L element after encountering minimum

Comment: Please don't use `l` (ell) as a variable name, it is too easily confused with `1` (one). I was about to say the the only condition that satisfies `i<j<=i+1` is `j=i+1`. Be informative, imaginative. How the devil is anyone going to know what a function argument `int l` is for?

Comment: Point noted @weather

Comment: So `min` should change if `max` changes then.  Disagree with [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358199/maximum-profit-of-stock-selling-such-that-there-is-atmost-l-days-difference-be?noredirect=1#comment66046878_39358199).  You have a sliding window of 5 or  `l` days.  As that window slides, the `min` needs to update also.  OTOH perhaps I do not follow the problem right.

Comment: You are right Cox..  Just I need to update minimum after windows closes. I'm trying to solve In linear time,  if you have any suggestion tell me. Thnx

Comment: I see an `O(n*l)` solution, but not `O(n)`.  Each time min falls out of the windows, find new min.  Will ponder.  I suspect a `O(n+l)` solution exists

Comment: @chux I believe I've found such an `O(n)` solution, if you would like to review it.

Answer (score 2):

So for each `i`, we need the minimum in `[i - len, i-1]`. We can do this using a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) that we will keep sorted ascendingly from front to back. The first element will always be the minimum. We will store indexes in the deque, not actual values.

```
st.push_back(0)
max_profit = 0
for i = 1 to size - 1:
    while !st.empty() && i - st.front() > len: // remove elements farther than len from i 
        st.pop_front()
    if array[i] - array[ st.front() ] > max_profit:
        max_profit = array[i] - array[ st.front() ]

    // add array[i] to the deque, while keeping it sorted.
    while !st.empty() && array[ st.back() ] > array[i]:
        st.pop_back()
    st.push_back(i)
```

Since each element can enter and leave the deque at most once, this is `O(n)`.

Comment: This is certainly a `O(size)` algorithm.  Likely functions as desired - unable to review that at this time.